# Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position

Tags: android, debugging, kotlin

I'm getting this error in Android Studio. I just want to print the text when I push the button. I get the below error, which appears every time I press the button. If I uncomment out the intent it works perfectly fine as well, but the more code I have the more the error changes. I am not actually sure this is the true error. I say this because I have an entire app (not this one) that uses retrofit and github api to search for repos. This button is the nexus for searching. If I hard code in a word the app works perfectly. I finally got to this simplified app in an attempt to find the root cause. Please help.

1.

```
10-17 15:33:56.569 1404-1431/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 2045606 , only wrote 1793520
```

2. This is the code

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.searchEditText)
        val searchEditText = editText.text.toString()


        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.searchButton)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            println(searchEditText)
            //val intent = Intent(this,SearchResultActivity::class.java)
            //intent.putExtra("searchTerm",searchEditText)
            //startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

3. This is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.blah.test236">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SearchResultActivity" />
</application>
```

4. This is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dnarialpressley.test236.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/searchButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchEditText" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: i am facing same problem while integrating google map in android app using java....same error is showing in logcat....if you had found any solution then please reply this comment.

Answer (score 1):

XML are fine but the main activity class is not using kotlin in the right way, in order to bind your items from your layout you can use **synthetic** native library like this

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.* // this imports all your items from your layout

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val searchEditText = searchEditText.text.toString() 
        // you can now use any items in the layout just by calling them

        searchButton.setOnClickListener{
            println(searchEditText)
        }

    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am testing this on 2 computers. When I add this line of code it greys itself out and says it's an unused import directive. I think my actual problem was the result of the OpenJDK platform in the background. I say this because once I ended the process in combination with deleting and reinstalling the emulator files, it now does as I want.

Comment: hmm You have to delete this lines (import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText) and everything else but the code on the answer it should work

Comment: Well I am once again getting the same error and I now have exactly what you have and nothing else. No greyed out items or other activities.  Also getting this errror.          10-18 11:31:46.031 1470-1483/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
10-18 11:31:46.031 1470-1483/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1

Comment: Yeah, at this point seems to be an external affecting your IDE, i will recommend uninstalling Java and Android Studio,  and installing the new RC1 which has full support for kotlin https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html#mac-canary-bundle, Hope it helps

Comment: hey...i am facing same error when i integrate google map in my android app. logcat showing same error. 
`02-19 16:41:58.950 1429-1457/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 2582927 , only wrote 2582640`
i am using java so this solution you had given is not for me. please tell me if you have any other solution. @AndreBreton

Answer (score 0):

Change you class code to this

```
    val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.searchEditText)
    val searchEditText = editText.text.toString()


    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.searchButton)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        println(searchEditText)
        //val intent = Intent(this,SearchResultActivity::class.java)
        //intent.putExtra("searchTerm",searchEditText)
        //startActivity(intent)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }
  }
```

Here we have just moved the "override" statement to the very end. I faced a similar issue but in Java, and when I moved the override function to the bottom, I didn't see that issue anymore. I hope it works for Kotlin as well.

Comment: @user10844401 in Kotlin? Because it worked fine in Java. What error would it be?

Comment: How? your activity is not the owner of the view (in which the button resides) until you call setContentView or Inflate on it.